# Insert google maps autocomplete input when no result in jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, google-maps, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have an input with jQuery autocomplete on it. The available tags for the autocompletion are cities or countries.

When there is no result, I'd want to append HTML as result with an google map autocompletion field.

I hardly managed to did it but when I select (by clicking) a city suggested by google map, the jQuery autocomplete close...

1. Type 'x'
2. Right-click on 'location' (there is a bug, nothing happens when left-click on 'location' field...) and then enter a location 'ie New York')
3. Left-click on the 'New York' suggestion and the autocompletion close!

http://jsfiddle.net/8GnZB/31/

```
$( "#addresspicker" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);
        if (!results.length) {
            results = [EmptyResult];
        }
        response(results);
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
        if ($('.ui-autocomplete').last().children().text() == EmptyResult) {
            $('.ui-autocomplete').append("<li><b>Please, enter a location:</b>" +
                            "<form action='/asking_user_locations' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>" +
                            "<input name='info[where]' id='address_picker_place' maxlength='255' type='text' placeholder='Location' required>" +
                            "<input name='info[email]' id='address_picker_email' maxlength='255' type='email' placeholder='email' required>" +
                            "<input name='commit' type='submit' value='submit'></form></li>");

                            new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('address_picker_place'), { types: ['(cities)'] })

        }
    }
});
```

**I don't want the autocompletion form to close, can you help me?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you're using the right approach by appending the maps form directly to the results. I think you should put the form in a separate div and show/hide it whenever necessary.

Something like that:

```
<input id="addresspicker" style="width: 200px; position: relative;">
<div id='maps-autocomplete' style="position: absolute; border: 1px solid #b1b1b1; top: 28px; width: 204px;display:none;">
  <b>Please, enter a location:</b>
  <form action='/asking_user_locations' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>                     
    <input name='info[where]' id='address_picker_place' maxlength='255' type='text' placeholder='Location' required="true" /><br/>
    <input name='info[email]' id='address_picker_email' maxlength='255' type='email' placeholder='email' required="true"/><br/>
    <input id="maps-commit" name='commit' type='submit' value='submit'/></form>
</div>
```

And the JS would be:

```
$(function() {
    var EmptyResult = "";
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('address_picker_place'), { types: ['(cities)'] })
    $( "#addresspicker" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);
            if(!results.length) { $("#maps-autocomplete").show();}

            response(results);
        },
  });
});
```

Of course after that, you should make sure that you hide and clear the form if something is typed into the original input etc..

Check on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nq3Nj/